# URL Rewrite for Jira using context.xml and rewrite.config (apache?)

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, jira, url-rewrite-module

I have a jira install on a single box. All Windows. I can't for the life of me get this to work. Is the following possible? Sometimes the first redirect works but that's it.

- Can I use sub.subdomain.domain.com?
- And for the last redirect, can I rewrite the url for the same domain?
- I have no idea if the syntax like the preceding ^ is correct. I've tried every combination I can think up but can't make it work.
- I've also tried the Tuckey filter and that didn't seem to work. I opened a case with Jira and they said this is the best way to do it but wasn't sure why this doesn't work. We followed this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-customize-customer-portal-url-in-jira-service-desk-server-847755218.html

Anway I'd love for someone to help solve this. Or solve it.
Thanks!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^it\.servicedesk\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://servicedesk.domain.org/projects/ITSD/queues [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard\.servicedesk\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://servicedesk.domain.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servicedesk\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://servicedesk.domain.org/servicedesk/customer/portals [R=301,L]
```